# A function that encrypts files taking too much time to finish

Tags: python, encryption

I have a program that encrypts my files in a specific location. I built a function for this that loops through the length of a list that stores my files, so if I have 12 files, it will loop 12 times. and then I'm looping through my directory, opening each file for reading and writing bytes and encrypt their data and write it to the file.

The function is working fine, but my problem is that my function is taking a long time to finish, and I don't know why.

Is there any way to improve the performance of my function ?

**Encrypt Function:**

This function is taking a lot of time to finish.

```
def encrypt(self):
        for _ in range(0, len(files())):
            for file in files():
                try:
                    with open(file, 'rb+') as f:
                        plain_text = f.read()
                        cipher_text = self.token.encrypt(plain_text)
                        f.seek(0); f.truncate()
                        f.write(cipher_text)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'{e}')
```

**Files Function:**

```
def files(pattern='*'):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in chain(os.walk(desktop_path), os.walk(downloads_path), os.walk(documents_path), os.walk(pictures_path)):
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if filter([full_path], pattern):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

Comment: What is `self.token`?

Comment: @guidot just call it like this: `token = Fernet(key)`, I'm using the `cryptography.fernet` to encrypt my files. I'm using `self` because I'm doing it in a class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you looping over the files nested?

```
for _ in range(0, len(files())):
    for file in files():
```

should be just

```
for file in files():
```

If you had 12 files the old code would encrypt each file 12 times.

Comment: Hey, I want my function to stop when it finish, this is why I'm using range

Comment: It will when the `files()` iterable ends.